# Developer Story: Confirm delete buttons confuse me

Tags: bug, developer-story, user-experience

When deleting data from my Developer Story Timeline, I am asked for confirmation ("Are you sure you want to do this?"). The confirmation shows two buttons as possible answers: "No" and "Yes". "No" keeps my data, "Yes" destroys it.

The buttons are colored red and green. I feel it should be the exact opposite: The button destroying my data should be colored red (big red button!) and the button getting me back to safety should be green.

(I had accidentally clicked the delete (X) icon, was a bit startled and hastily almost clicked the green button to get back. That would have confirmed my error.)

[image: Screenshot when deleting data from my developer story with totally hand drawn markings]

Comment: I disagree: for me, red button means "no" and green button means "yes", so for "Are you sure you want to do this?", whatever *"this"* is, dangerous or not, it should be green for "Yes".

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Eric. I did some more research and took the liberty of editing the title of my question so it's about my problem, not about the current implementation so much.

Comment: Very good link in your answer, thank you for posting it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I now found a good answer to my question at the UX Stack Exchange:

- [Should “Yes, delete it” be red, or green?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49991/should-yes-delete-it-be-red-or-green/)

  - Answer: [Neither, both ways seem to pose a false-positive paradigm. Use "Delete" and "Cancel".](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/49994)

(Answering my own question after reading Eric's comment. For most issues, there are agreed-upon best practices in UI, and opinions shouldn't matter much. This is craft, after all, not art.)

Comment: Don't know if it's fine on meta as well to accept my own answer... hope I'm doing this right.

Comment: I can see how it'd be confusing though. I'll change the copy to "Yes, delete it" and change the colors too.

Answer (score 0):

I am in support of the answer given by @Florian Sesser. I have been involved in a good amount of web designing and development, and we have always been using the **red color for dangerous situations**, and that intuitive as well.

**People tend to click the green button without reading the text and always read what's written in red.**

So, in the above scenario, where **clicking yes is dangerous** because if you click yes, you lose the data, and thus is it counter-intuitive to put green as the color of yes. No one would want to carelessly click the green button and lose the data when the actual intention was to cancle the operation and click no.